# Laravel Route Resource both GET and POST

Tags: php, laravel, post, get, routes

I have this `Route`

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth','lang']], function() {

    // SETTINGS
    Route::namespace( 'Settings' )->prefix( 'settings' )->group( function () {

        // INDEX
        Route::get( '/', 'SettingsController@index' );

        // ACCOUNTS
        Route::resource( 'accounts', 'AccountController', ['only' => ['index','store','edit','update']] );

        // TAGS
        Route::resource( 'tags', 'TagController', ['only' => ['index','destroy']] );

        // PROFILE
        Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@index');
        Route::post('profile', 'ProfileController@update');

    });
```

Any way I can join the two PROFILE ones into one that is `resource`? Whenever I try using `Route::resource( 'profile', 'ProfileController', ['only' => ['index','update']] )`, it gives me an error that the method is not allowed - `405 (Method Not Allowed)`. I think it just doesn't find the `update` one? I am really not sure what might be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in the case of resourceful controllers, a post would be defaulted to a store method, not update.

So you are posting to the store method, which is not defined, giving you the 403 method not allowed.

To solve this, either change your request to a PUT or  change your code to `Route::resource( 'profile', 'ProfileController', ['only' => ['index','store']] )` Keep in mind, if you do this, you have to move the contents of your update function to store.

For more information, checkout https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!